# How can I find the nature of a turning point?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I have this function which has 4 turning points:

$$f(x)=18m^4 x+42m^3 x^2-54m^2 x^3-42 m x^4+36x^5$$
`f(x)==18m^4 x+42m^3 x^2-54m^2 x^3-42 m x^4+36x^5`

However, I can't seem to find out how to use the same function to find the nature of the points. Am I missing something? I'm quite new to Mathematica.

Comment: What range of `x` and `m` are you interested in?  What are the four turning points you found? Can you show the code you've used so far?

Comment: x is just an arbetrary variable, i apoligise for not specifying the value of m, it is 0.89003. The turning points are at {{x -> -0.693447}, {x -> -0.151408}, {x -> 0.514972}, {x -> 1.16058}} , the code i have currently is : "m = 0.89003
b[x_] := 18 m^4 x + 42 m^3 x^2 - 54 m^2 x^3 - 42 m x^4 + 36 x^5 / Solve[b'[x] == 0] // N / {{x -> -0.693447}, {x -> -0.151408}, {x -> 0.514972}, {x -> 1.16058}}"

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[m_, x_] := 18 m^4 x + 42 m^3 x^2 - 54 m^2 x^3 - 42 m x^4 + 36 x^5

max[m_] = Solve[{D[f[m, x], x] == 0, D[f[m, x], {x, 2}] < 0}, x, Reals];

min[m_] = Solve[{D[f[m, x], x] == 0, D[f[m, x], {x, 2}] > 0}, x, Reals];

With[{m = 0.89003},
 Plot[f[m, x], {x, -1, 1.5},
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Red, Tooltip[Point[{x, f[m, x]}], {x, f[m, x]}] /. max[m],
    Blue, Tooltip[Point[{x, f[m, x]}], {x, f[m, x]}] /. min[m]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    PointLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"maxima", "minima"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 13],
    {0.75, 0.75}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: For generality you should probably add something like `indet[m_] = Solve[{D[f[m, x], x] == 0, D[f[m, x], {x, 2}] == 0}, x, Reals];` for the critical points that may or may not be extremal.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I considered that, but my guess at what was meant by “turning points” did not include inflection points, i.e., where the curve is flat.

Answer (score 3):

If by "turning points" you mean the values of $x$ where $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=0$, then the following will get you what you want:

```
f[x_] := 18 m^4 x + 42 m^3 x^2 - 54 m^2 x^3 - 42 m x^4 + 36 x^5
Reduce[D[f[x], x] == 0, x] // N
(* x == -0.779128 m || x == -0.170115 m || x == 0.578601 m || x == 1.30398 m *)
```